# How to customize Devise_invitable generated forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, devise, devise-invitable

The form path is `user/invitations/invitations/edit.html.erb` and `new.html.erb`

Edit.html.erb

```
    <h2><%= t 'devise.invitations.edit.header' %></h2>
    <%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => invitation_path(resource_name),  :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :invitation_token %>

    <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %></p>

    <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

    <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

    <p><%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.edit.submit_button") %></p>
    <% end %>
```

I added the following by myself in the `edit.html.erb` but the form isn't showing up the fields

```
    <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %></p>
```

Please let me know how to deal with this. And customize forms for devise_invitable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Generated views again by following command:

```
    rails generate devise_invitable:views users
```

and then found that the nesting done users/invitations/invitaions/edit.html.erb was wrong.

It should be like views/users/invitations/edit.html.erb

This solved my problem and now i am able to customize devise_invitable form.

Answer (score 1):

Your replacement form should go here

```
app/views/devise/invitations/edit.html.erb
```

Comment: I did this before but that doesn't help